# Hide window indicator from the top bar on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: gnome-shell, appmenu

I am using Ubuntu 20.04. I have hidden the "*Activities*" button on the left side of top bar. Is there a way to hide where it shows what window is open, next to where "Activities" was?

For example, I want to hide "Google Chrome" from the upper left:
[image: screen shot]

The GNOME extension *TaskBar 2020* does not provide this function. I want to keep the top bar, just without showing what window is active.